# Deploying/Running jvm application on a remote-host from Intellij

Tags: java, intellij-idea, jvm

Would it be possible to deploy/run (for testing purposes) a standalone Java application on a remote server from intellij? I'm not trying to connect to an already running JVM, but to start a new JVM on the remote host from intellij just like it was running on my local machine?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no built-in support for it at the moment. You can deploy an application to an application server running on a remote machine, but if you have a standalone application, there is no built-in feature to deploy it.

That said, you can write an Ant script or a shell script to deploy your app, and use either the Ant integration or the external tool feature to run it from with in IntelliJ IDEA.

Comment: It appears that this is indeed the case. Thanks for the confirmation. Would be a nice feature though.

Comment: Similar support already exists for Python, PHP and Ruby, so it would not be a big surprise to see it implemented for Java as well.