# IntelliJ Idea: build and run Java apps in docker containers

Tags: java, intellij-idea, docker, spring-boot

In my project I'd like to containerize my Spring Boot applications not only on production environment but also locally. In order to do that I'd like to:

1. Start docker container (from a java image)
2. Click "run" in IntelliJ Idea
3. Build the application ***in*** the container (not using my local machine compiler but the one that is in the container)
4. Run the application ***in*** the container

Is such scenario possible? I do not want to use Gradle or Maven to build the application in the container - I want to tell IntelliJ Idea to use the inside docker container java compiler, not the one that i have locally.

Comment: Did you do any research before asking?

Comment: I've found similar (?) case mentioned here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28931403/deploying-running-jvm-application-on-a-remote-host-from-intellij

I also tried to utilize the IntelliJ Docker Plugin to achieve the goal, but it led me nowhere yet.

Comment: I don't think there's any way to run the IDE's Make within the container without running the whole IDE in the container to begin with, mostly because nobody ever thought it would be useful.

Comment: You're using docker wrong. Each container is meant to do one thing and only one thing, so you shouldn't be making the app /and/ running it in the same container -- your runtime container should only have the jre installed, not the jvm -- you're aiming for the smallest runtime you can get. And building with anything other than maven is a bad idea -- even gradle is crap by comparison. For reference: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36429949/intellij-use-docker-jvm-or-docker-maven

Comment: @OrangeDog, it's very useful e.g. to define exactly the same tools/versions etc for all the developers. In PyCharm (pythons' equivalent for IntelliJ) you can very easily define a remote interpreter and run the same set up on every environment - very, very useful.

Comment: @EngineerDollery, this is only development setup, trust me it's a a bit problematic to it in a correct and puristic way. On the other environments (staging and production) the setup looks differently.

Comment: @Opal then the developers should be running their tools (i.e. the whole IDE) inside the shared container/VM. Though as already said, this problem has already been solved by Maven, and is not what Docker is for.

Comment: @OrangeDog, problem was solved by maven? How? What if there are n developers and every single one has different version of jdk?

Comment: @Opal You specify the Java version with Maven.

Comment: @OrangeDog, if it was just a matter of a java version. What if project is set to 8 and few developers have 6 and can't install 8 because of other projects they work on? They have multiple JDKs installed and change `JAVA_HOME` value? This is not just a matter of java version but the whole ecosystem, env variables, config files, certificates and so on and so on. Why just don't use docker image to run a container that will unify all these stuff along with IDE that can run remotely an application?

Comment: @Opal Because that's not what Docker is for. All these problems are already solved by existing tools, which I won't go into now because it's not relevant to this question.

Comment: @OrangeDog these problems are not solved by other tools in ways Docker enables you to solve them (and we see Docker used like this i.e. in the Go Community). There are a couple of ways that allow you to run and debug inside a Docker container, but currently there is no real IntelliJ support i.e. for running tests with Gradle inside a container and test result parsing. I think we might need a Gradle plugin for this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What might be helpful is described [here](https://medium.com/@lhartikk/development-environment-in-spring-boot-with-docker-734ad6c50b34#.8fvo9zf5i). Basically you need [devtools](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/using-boot-devtools.html) and run a spring-boot application inside a docker container - musn't be done via `java -jar ...` - rather with maven or gradle plugins. Then setup a java application configuration with [RemoteSpringApplication](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current-SNAPSHOT/api/org/springframework/boot/devtools/RemoteSpringApplication.html) class and it should work.

Unfortunately I've experienced some problems, see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38222513/exception-on-reloading-remote-spring-boot-application-with-intellij-idea) question.