# Exception on reloading remote spring boot application with Intellij IDEA

Tags: macos, intellij-idea, docker, spring-boot, docker-machine

I'm trying to setup remote spring-boot environment using spring [devtools](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/using-boot-devtools.html), docker and IntelliJ. All started with this [article](https://medium.com/@lhartikk/development-environment-in-spring-boot-with-docker-734ad6c50b34#.z27jyzita). Unfortunately it randomly fails with an exception. Below the configuration:

**Dockerfile**

```
FROM        java:8

EXPOSE      8888

WORKDIR     /app

ADD         build.gradle    /app/build.gradle
ADD         gradlew         /app/gradlew
ADD         gradle          /app/gradle

ADD         src             /app/src

RUN         ["chmod", "+x", "/app/gradlew"]
```

**docker-compose.yml**

```
backend:
  build: .
  env_file: environment
  ports:
    - "8888:8888"
  volumes:
    - ./.gradle-docker:/root/.gradle
  command: "/app/gradlew clean bootRun"
  links:
    - db

db:
  image:  postgres:9.5.3
  env_file: environment
  ports:
    - "5454:5432"
```

The whole application is started from command line with: `docker-compose build` and `docker-compose up` commands.

In IntelliJ I've prepared the following java application configuration:
[image: configuration]

where `docker:8888` is the IP of the docker-machine and port that is used by spring application. After the configuration is run is the following output:

```
/\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _          ___               _      \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` |        | _ \___ _ __  ___| |_ ___ \ \ \ \
\\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| []::::::[]   / -_) '  \/ _ \  _/ -_) ) ) ) )
 '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, |        |_|_\___|_|_|_\___/\__\___|/ / / /
=========|_|==============|___/===================================/_/_/_/
:: Spring Boot Remote ::  (v1.3.5.RELEASE)

2016-07-06 12:48:51.997  INFO 17731 --- [           main] o.s.b.devtools.RemoteSpringApplication   : Starting RemoteSpringApplication v1.3.5.RELEASE on opal-mac.local with PID 17731 (/Users/opal/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-devtools/1.3.5.RELEASE/ab035bdc1e6297ff4c8676edd93ed307b11353c2/spring-boot-devtools-1.3.5.RELEASE.jar started by opal in /Users/opal/projects/backend)
2016-07-06 12:48:52.013  INFO 17731 --- [           main] o.s.b.devtools.RemoteSpringApplication   : No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
2016-07-06 12:48:52.106  INFO 17731 --- [           main] s.c.a.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext : Refreshing org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext@441772e: startup date [Wed Jul 06 12:48:52 CEST 2016]; root of context hierarchy
2016-07-06 12:48:54.016  WARN 17731 --- [           main] o.s.b.d.r.c.RemoteClientConfiguration    : The connection to http://docker:8888 is insecure. You should use a URL starting with 'https://'.
2016-07-06 12:48:54.419  WARN 17731 --- [           main] o.s.b.d.a.OptionalLiveReloadServer       : Unable to start LiveReload server
2016-07-06 12:48:54.499  INFO 17731 --- [           main] o.s.b.devtools.RemoteSpringApplication   : Started RemoteSpringApplication in 3.793 seconds (JVM running for 5.004)
```

Unfortunately after some change is made to the code, the following exception occurs:

```
2016-07-06 12:49:29.141  INFO 17731 --- [   File Watcher] o.s.b.d.r.c.ClassPathChangeUploader      : Uploaded 1 class resource
2016-07-06 12:49:31.056  INFO 17731 --- [   File Watcher] o.s.b.d.r.c.ClassPathChangeUploader      : Uploaded 1 class resource
Exception in thread "File Watcher" java.lang.IllegalStateException: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
    at org.springframework.boot.devtools.remote.client.ClassPathChangeUploader.onApplicationEvent(ClassPathChangeUploader.java:107)
    at org.springframework.boot.devtools.remote.client.ClassPathChangeUploader.onApplicationEvent(ClassPathChangeUploader.java:56)
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.invokeListener(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:166)
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:138)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.publishEvent(AbstractApplicationContext.java:381)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.publishEvent(AbstractApplicationContext.java:335)
    at org.springframework.boot.devtools.classpath.ClassPathFileChangeListener.publishEvent(ClassPathFileChangeListener.java:68)
    at org.springframework.boot.devtools.classpath.ClassPathFileChangeListener.onChange(ClassPathFileChangeListener.java:64)
    at org.springframework.boot.devtools.filewatch.FileSystemWatcher.fireListeners(FileSystemWatcher.java:230)
    at org.springframework.boot.devtools.filewatch.FileSystemWatcher.updateSnapshots(FileSystemWatcher.java:223)
    at org.springframework.boot.devtools.filewatch.FileSystemWatcher.scan(FileSystemWatcher.java:183)
    at org.springframework.boot.devtools.filewatch.FileSystemWatcher.access$100(FileSystemWatcher.java:41)
    at org.springframework.boot.devtools.filewatch.FileSystemWatcher$1.run(FileSystemWatcher.java:150)
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:350)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:206)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:188)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:589)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:538)
    at sun.net.NetworkClient.doConnect(NetworkClient.java:180)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:432)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:527)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.<init>(HttpClient.java:211)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.New(HttpClient.java:308)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.New(HttpClient.java:326)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getNewHttpClient(HttpURLConnection.java:1169)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect0(HttpURLConnection.java:1105)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect(HttpURLConnection.java:999)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.connect(HttpURLConnection.java:933)
    at org.springframework.http.client.SimpleBufferingClientHttpRequest.executeInternal(SimpleBufferingClientHttpRequest.java:80)
    at org.springframework.http.client.AbstractBufferingClientHttpRequest.executeInternal(AbstractBufferingClientHttpRequest.java:48)
    at org.springframework.http.client.AbstractClientHttpRequest.execute(AbstractClientHttpRequest.java:53)
    at org.springframework.http.client.InterceptingClientHttpRequest$InterceptingRequestExecution.execute(InterceptingClientHttpRequest.java:93)
    at org.springframework.boot.devtools.remote.client.HttpHeaderInterceptor.intercept(HttpHeaderInterceptor.java:57)
    at org.springframework.http.client.InterceptingClientHttpRequest$InterceptingRequestExecution.execute(InterceptingClientHttpRequest.java:85)
    at org.springframework.http.client.InterceptingClientHttpRequest.executeInternal(InterceptingClientHttpRequest.java:69)
    at org.springframework.http.client.AbstractBufferingClientHttpRequest.executeInternal(AbstractBufferingClientHttpRequest.java:48)
    at org.springframework.http.client.AbstractClientHttpRequest.execute(AbstractClientHttpRequest.java:53)
    at org.springframework.boot.devtools.remote.client.ClassPathChangeUploader.onApplicationEvent(ClassPathChangeUploader.java:102)
    ... 12 more
```

In docker and IntelliJ:

```
2016-07-06 12:49:29.141  INFO 17731 --- [   File Watcher] o.s.b.d.r.c.ClassPathChangeUploader      : Uploaded 1 class resource
```

logs I see that the context is reloaded. What may be the problem?

Comment: It looks like the connection to `docker:8888` is unreliable. The first `Uploaded 1 class resource` without an exception shows that a change was successfully uploaded. The second, only two seconds later, shows that a connection couldn't be made. What, if anything, is logged by the app running in Docker while this is going on?

Comment: @AndyWilkinson after the first update application that is run in Docker starts to reload. Then the second update is made which results in _Connection refused_ since there's no context at that time.

Comment: With apologies for sending you round in circles, now that I understand what's going on it's clear that this is a bug in DevTools. I've opened https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/6339

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's a [bug](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/6339) in Spring boot's DevTools which means that if you make a change to your application while the restart that was triggered by the previous change is still in progress, the attempt to upload the changes will fail. I think we probably need to update DevTools to retry the upload attempt.

In the meantime, the only "solution" is to stop and restart your `RemoteSpringApplication` whenever you see the failure due to `java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused`.

Comment: Thank you very much! Can I help somehow? Also: is there any estimated time for providing a fix?